# Automorphisms of punctured half upper plane

Tags: complex-analysis, automorphism-group

We know the form of automorphisms of the upper half plane. But I'm asked to calculate the set of automorphism of the upper half plane without a point (in this case is without i).
I have tried to analyze the isolated singularity when z=i and I've come to the conclusion that it can't be an essential singularity, and if it's an removable singularity it's necessarily  f(i)=i
But I'm not sure how to proceed if i it's a pole.
Any idea?

Comment: if instead of the punctured upper half plane you look at a punctured disk (they are isomorphic, so it's OK), you will not have to fight with poles

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't see that. Thanks!